# Alternate to Web Service C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, client

I am looking for an alternate to web services.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
On a server, I have a database with a lot of information on it. My clients will use a desktop application to securely log on and make changes and then log off.

At first, I had planned to create a web service, with methods to make changes and connect to database. But for reasons, I have to look towards something else.

Could please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: What reasons do you have for not using web services? If you explain, we can figure out an appropriate solution, instead of guessing.

Comment: He specifically explained the requirements - and people interrogate him instead of answering the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WCF to implement a service with interchangeable "bindings"

> **Binding.** The binding specifies how to communicate with the endpoint. The binding specifies how the endpoint communicates with the world, including which transport protocol to use (for example, TCP or HTTP), which encoding to use for the messages (for example, text or binary), and which security requirements are necessary (for example, Secure Sockets Layer [SSL] or SOAP message security). For more information, see Using Bindings to Configure Services and Clients.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735096.aspx

See ["System-Provided Bindings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx) for some options.

- NetTcpBinding - A secure and optimized binding suitable for cross-machine communication between WCF applications

Comment: WCF does look a bit complex, but I will definitely look into it. Thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a "web-services", one could look at other tools such [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/iceVsCorba.html) which is similar -- in ways -- to CORBA and RMI (and I would dare say parts of WCF). Or, perhaps RPC with Protocol Buffers, [Apache Thrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift), or even "just" [OData](http://www.odata.org/), etc -- no shortage of tooling, libraries or approaches.

Will any of these alternatives "be better" than "web-services"? It depends, of course... I would focus on keeping it simple and making it Just Work though :)

Happy coding.

Comment: OData **IS** web services - it's based on WCF REST .....

Comment: Yeh, I need to keep it simple too. For now, I'm looking into WCF and talking to my client about it. Thanks for the wonderful advice. :)